# Unable to start ws02 application server on Windows - error "The system cannot find the batch label specified - commandLifecycle"

Tags: wso2

I downloaded wso2 application server 5.0.0.  I placed it on my windows server and attempted to execute wso2server.bat --run.  When I do that, I receive this error:

The system cannot find the batch label specified - commandLifecycle

If I look in the wso2server.bat file, I see that the commandLifecycle label doesn't exist.

Has anyone else run into this same issue?

Edit: I just tried running 4.1.2 and I did not have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I just run the shell: wso2server.bat without the parameter [--run] and it start ok.